# How to create a master function in 1 file that I can call for different View Controllers in Swift

Tags: swift, function

I have a few View Controllers that contains the same functions over and over. Is it possible to create a new file, of a certain type, where I can put those functions in and call it from my View Controller? That way, I don't have duplicate code so much.

Let's say this is my function, that I am using on a few other view controllers as well:

```
func StartUpEveryLevel() {
    AllCards.removeAll()
    scoreText.text = String(score)
}
```

How can I place this in a new file, and call it up and to stuff to that particular view controller?

Thx!

Comment: This is a very broad question and not the type for Stackoverflow, but here is a link to learn a bit about `Object Orientated Programming` https://www.raywenderlich.com/81952/intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Protocols and Extensions.

Create a new Swift file `StartProtocol.swift` with the following content.

```
protocol StartProtocol { }

extension StartProtocol {
    func startUpEveryLevel() {
        // your logic goes here
    }
}
```

Now let's open every one of your `ViewControllers`.
You just need to make them conform to `StartProtocol` in order to receive the `startUpEveryLevel` method.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, StartProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startUpEveryLevel()
    }
}
```